# Translation of modules

Tags: webforms, i18n-l10n, captcha

I am using Drupal 7.9 and Webform 3.15. I need to translate **-select-** option on top of list box. Also I have to translate in Captcha module (7.x-1.0-beta2), the text **What code is in the image?** and **Enter the characters shown in the image**. How can do this?

How can I translate modules to required language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to switch on the [Locale](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/locale) module, which is part of Drupal  core. There you can search for the strings you want to translate.

If you  want to translate an entire module from scratch, I suggest that you read about translation on drupal.org and make yourself familiar with the toolchain. It's fairly straightforward.